# Expand search input field while input within a div using CSS 3

Tags: html, css, frontend

I created a custom 'searchbox'. The 'searchbox' actually built by a div and input text inside it.
Later on I will add a 'search' icon on the left and 'clear' button on the right.

The issue is, the input inside the div already sized based on it's container and when I'm focusing the input text, I couldn't find a way to expand the parent div (instead of the input itself). It's important the div will expand so the icons and buttons I will later add - will expand with the input.
Couldn't find a way doing it with CSS only (without JS).

Will appreciate your assistance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tan;
}

.fieldcontainer {
  display: flex;

  padding-left: 8px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-color: grey;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 35px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: default;
  transition: 'background-color' 0.4s;
}

.fieldcontainer:hover {
  background-color: #C3C3C3;
}

.searchfield {
  background-color: inherit;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 0;
  flex-grow: 8;
  
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.searchfield:focus {
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="App">
  <div class="fieldcontainer">
    <input class="searchfield" type="text" placeholder="search" />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `focus-within` (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tan;
}

.fieldcontainer {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 8px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-color: grey;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 35px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: default;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.fieldcontainer:hover {
  background-color: #C3C3C3;
}

.searchfield {
  background-color: inherit;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 0;
  flex-grow: 8;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  outline:none;
}

.fieldcontainer:focus-within {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="fieldcontainer">
    <input class="searchfield" type="text" placeholder="search" />
  </div>
</div>
```